# PHP remove collection item from array if one value of collection is empty

Tags: php, arrays

I have array with this structure:

```
$array = [
         0=> ["field"=1, "value"="strawberry"]
         1=> ["field"=2, "value"=null]
         2=> ["field"=3, "value"="apple"]
         ]
```

How to iterate this `$array`, so it's deletes objects where `value==null`? After Iteration my array should look like:

```
$array = [
         0=> ["field"=1, "value"="strawberry"]
         1=> ["field"=3, "value"="apple"]
         ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilise the [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to keep the array keys in-tact whilst removing null values. Using [Arrow Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) in PHP 7.4^ you can try:

```
array_filter($array, fn($arr) => !is_null($arr['value']))
```

Output:

```
Array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'field' => 1,
    'value' => 'strawberry',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'field' => 3,
    'value' => 'apple',
  ),
)
```

See it working over at [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Z24bC) - OP said `!is_null()` is required in the comment section and may need to be used.

If you want to reset the array keys you can use [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

Comment: I modified your answer and it worked. My modified answer is: 
` return   array_filter($array, fn ($arr) => !is_null($arr['value']));` . You can edit your answer and this as well and I will accept it as solution

Comment: `!is_null()` shouldn't be needed as shown in the example over at 3v4l.org however, I will update the question to add this information for future viewers. Glad I could help. @Raskoljnikovic